# PHP undefined variable and function name must be a string error

Tags: php

```
$A="67452301";
$B="EFCDAB89";
$C="98BADCFE";
$D="10325476";

function F($X, $Y, $Z)  
{
    $X = hexdec($X);
    $Y = hexdec($Y);
    $Z = hexdec($Z);
    $calc = (($X & $Y) | ((~ $X) & $Z)); // X AND Y OR NOT X AND Z
    return  $calc; 
}

$cal=$F($B,$C,$D);
echo $cal;
```

This is the error I receive from the above code:

> Undefined variable: F and that function name must be a string.

Comment: $cal=F($B,$C,$D); use this,

Comment: drop the $ before the F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only call function using its name

You do not need to add `$` before any function name:

```
$cal = F($B,$C,$D);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (Don't add $ in-front of function name):-

```
$A="67452301";
$B="EFCDAB89";
$C="98BADCFE";
$D="10325476";

function F($X, $Y, $Z)  
{
    $X = hexdec($X);
    $Y = hexdec($Y);
    $Z = hexdec($Z);
    $calc = (($X & $Y) | ((~ $X) & $Z)); // X AND Y OR NOT X AND Z
    return  $calc; 
}

$cal = F($B,$C,$D);
echo $cal;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Function`, `Named/Referenced Function` and a `Variable` are not the same things. While a `Referenced Function` can be called like a `Function`; a variable can not — except if it is referencing another callable `Function`.

`$F=function(){echo 'Peace';}` can be called like so: `$F();` without problems...

However; `$F = null;` `$F();` is syntactically incorrect....

And except in the case of a `Referenced Function`; you may not have a `$` before your Function calls....  You code should have read something like this:

```
    <?php
        $A  = "67452301";
        $B  = "EFCDAB89";
        $C  = "98BADCFE";
        $D  = "10325476";

        function F($X, $Y, $Z){
            $X     = hexdec($X);
            $Y     = hexdec($Y);
            $Z     = hexdec($Z);
            $calc  = (($X & $Y) | ((~ $X) & $Z)); // X AND Y OR NOT X AND Z
            return  $calc; 
        }

        $cal  = F($B,$C,$D);
        echo $cal;    
    ?>
```